# Incorrect Routing is ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I don't know why I have such problems with ASP.NET MVC routing. I wish there was a tool that showed me which routes I had currently setup. Regardless,

In my global.asax.cs file I have the following:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute(
    "SignUp", // Route name
    "account/{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Register" } // Parameter defaults
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
  );
}
```

I have the following defined in HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
  return View();
}
```

I was expecting to be able to access this page by visiting */account/register* in my browser. However, I continue to get a 404. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "SignUp", // Route name
    "account/{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Register" } // Parameter defaults
  );
```

with

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "SignUp", // Route name
    "account/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home" } // Parameter defaults
  );
```

This will mean `/account/register` will route to the Register action on the Home controller. It will also mean that action links and other links you generate via `@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Home")` will generate the URL `/account/register`

Think of the 'URL with paramters' as a pattern that the URL will be matched against.

The problem with your original route map is that it is looking for a URL like this `/account/controllername/actionname`.  So, when you go `/account/register` - it is taking `register` as the controller name, and taking the default action name (in this case register) - and as the 'register' action does not exist in the 'register' controller - you are getting a 404.

**UPDATED**
I updated my suggested route as per Robert's comments.

It is also worth noting, as Robert states, that this whole thing could be made more simple by making a 'Account' controller, and moving the 'Register ' action there.  Then you could delete the 'SignUp' route, and just use default routing.  If you thought about it, you'd agree that this would be a better place for a 'Register' action than the 'Home' controller.

Comment: to actually use `account/register` they should remove default action value because otherwise registration would be accessible from `account` only. Generated URLs will never have the word *register* in them. If you write URL manually it will of course work just as well.

Comment: BTW: I would also recommend (and is likely not the case) to avoid having account actions in `HomeController`. It would be better to have it elsewhere. `AccountController` maybe? Well in that case default routing would still apply, because controller's name would be *account*... Which means that OP is most likely overcomplicating their routing for no obvious benefit. They should rather just stay with default routing and separate controller...

Answer (score 3):

`/Account/Register` matches your first route.

The word `Register` is matched to the `{controller}`, so it looks for a controller named `RegisterController`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this nugget package http://nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.Mvc3
You can find more info about **glimpse** on http://getglimpse.com/